# Android Volley Gson Exception

Tags: android, json, gson, android-volley

I am using volley in my app for network requests.I am trying to use GSON library for JSON parsing and create a list view with that.JSON looks like this.When I try to run the code I got an exception. What is wrong with this and what is missing

```
[
{
    "articles": {
        "code": "/par/feed_sub_section",
        "name": "News",
        "title": "News",
        "count": "25",
        "page": "1",
        "totalPages": "11",
        "expiryTime": 100
    },
    "article": [
        {
            "title": "title 1",
            "articleUrl": "articleUrl 1",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail 1",
            "imgWeb": "imgWeb 1",
            "imgMob": "imgMob 1",
            "lastModified": "lastModified1",
            "otherImages": "0",
            "video": "false"
        },
        {
            "title": "title2",
            "articleUrl": "articleUrl2",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail2",
            "imgWeb": "imgWeb2",
            "imgMob": "imgMob2",
            "lastModified": "lastModified2",
            "otherImages": "0",
            "video": "false"
        },
        {
            "title": "title3",
            "articleUrl": "articleUrl3",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail3",
            "imgWeb": "imgWeb3",
            "imgMob": "imgMob3",
            "lastModified": "lastModified3",
            "otherImages": "0",
            "video": "false"
        },
        {
            "title": "title4",
            "articleUrl": "articleUrl4",
            "thumbnail": "thumbnail4",
            "imgWeb": "imgWeb4",
            "imgMob": "imgMob4",
            "lastModified": "lastModified4",
            "otherImages": "0",
            "video": "false"
        }
    ]
}]
```

and my classes is like

```
  public class Article {

String title;
String articleUrl;
String thumbnail;
String imgWeb;
String imgMob;
String lastModified;
String otherImages;
String video;}


public class Articles {
String code;
String name;
String title;
String count;
String page;

public class ArticleMainObject {
public Articles articles;
public List<Article> articleList;}
```

I use volley and try to parse result like this

```
GsonRequest<ArticleMainObject> myReq = new GsonRequest<ArticleMainObject >(Method.GET,
                                                "http://JSONURL/",
                                                ArticleMainObject .class,
                                                createMyReqSuccessListener(),
                                                createMyReqErrorListener());
```

When i run this code i got exception like this

```
com.android.volley.ParseError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 4 column 2
```

I am stuck at this point.How to iterate through the result.I am new to GSON.So please help me

Comment: try to pass Array  like `ArticleMainObject[].class` and `ArticleMainObject[]`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK   tried it .Exception is gone.But result is null

Comment: Check GSON api's for getting string as JSONArray